# Solidity contract does not update variable when calling it from web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, npm

my solidity code compiled using solcjs

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.4;
contract FirstContract {
  int count = 0;
  function incr() public{
    count = 15;
  }
  function decr() public{
    count = 10;
  }
  function display() public view returns (int){
    return count;
  }
}
```

Compiled the aboove code in counter.js using node counter.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
const bytecode = fs.readFileSync('build/counter_sol_FirstContract.bin');
const abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('build/counter_sol_FirstContract.abi'));

(async function () {
  const ganacheAccounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const myWalletAddress = ganacheAccounts[0];

  const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

  myContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode.toString()
  }).send({
    from: myWalletAddress,
    gas: 5000000
  }).then((deployment) => {
    console.log('voting was successfully deployed!');
    console.log('voting can be interfaced with at this address:');
    console.log(deployment.options.address);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
})();
```

And finally my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>First DApp</title>
</head>

<body>

  Increment
  <button id="incr">+</button>
  <br>
  Decrement
  <button id="decr">-</button>
  <br />
  <label id="myLabel"></label>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.2.6/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script>

  const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

  const myContractAddress = '0xEE22eF9B315E396933231Cd86a069d1ea6763DD7';
  const myAbi = [{"inputs":[],"name":"decr","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"display","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"incr","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
  const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myAbi, myContractAddress);

  const htmlLabel = document.getElementById('myLabel');
  myContract.methods.display().call().then((jsonRpcResult) => {
      htmlLabel.innerHTML = jsonRpcResult;
      console.log(jsonRpcResult);
    });
  $('#incr').click(function () {
    myContract.methods.incr().call();
  });
  $('#decr').click(function () {
    myContract.methods.decr().call();
  });


</script>

</html>
```

Basically trying to run a counter using solidity but it is not updating for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`methods.xxx().call()` is a read-only function. It cannot update the blockchain state. Thus, your `incr().call()` just returts the result of `incr` function without updating anything.

To update a state you need to you us [methods.xxx().send()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).

Comment: I tried using send() but issue i faced there was it did not incremented the counter value if i write the below function  function incr() public{
    count ++;
  }, It returned the initial value which is 0

Answer (score 0):

Your `incr` and `decr` functions should be used by: `.send()`
because you updating your `count` state variable on a blockchain, after this you should call your `display` function after updating your variable. it looks you want to get `count` in a `incr` function, but this function does not return anything, it just update your variable.